# Allow two datetime format using raise ValueError python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, valueerror

I have two csv files with two different format which are `'%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S'` and `'%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S'`. Hence, I will get such ValueError :

```
ValueError: time data '14/12/2020 17:43:15' does not match format '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S'
```

Sample data from `file1.csv` where month is in the middle:

```
timestamp             
15/12/2020 11:01:54
15/12/2020 11:02:54
15/12/2020 13:33:24
```

While `file2.csv`, month is at front :

```
timestamp            
12/15/2020 11:01:54
12/15/2020 11:02:54
12/15/2020 13:33:24
```

The column comes as String then I require to transform to only extract out the `date`.
This is the code :

```
responses_df['date_only'] = [datetime.strptime(val, format='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S').date() for val in responses_df['timestamp']]
```

My plan is to redirect `format=` to a function that will overcome `ValueError` and change the format from `'%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S'` to `'%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S'`.

Something like this.. :

```
responses_df['date_only'] = [datetime.strptime(val, format=get_format()).date() for val in responses_df['timestamp']]


def get_format():
     if ValueError is raised, use '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S'
     else, use '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S'
```

Comment: Please include sample input data with both data formats in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with

```
s1 = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'],format='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S', errors='coerce')
s2 = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'],format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S', errors='coerce')
```

Then

```
df['new']=s1.fillna(s2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming two files read in as two different dataframes before you join into a single `df` -- for the first file, pass `dayfirst=True`. For the second file, do not. Then, convert both to desired format with `dt.strftime()`:

```
df1['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['timestamp'], dayfirst=True).dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')
df2['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['timestamp']).dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')
df1, df2
Out[1]: 
(             timestamp
 0  15/12/2020 11:01:54
 1  15/12/2020 11:02:54
 2  15/12/2020 13:33:24,
              timestamp
 0  15/12/2020 11:01:54
 1  15/12/2020 11:02:54
 2  15/12/2020 13:33:24)
```